# Error while installing MySQL on RedHat Linux

Tags: mysql, linux, redhat

I am new to RedHat Linux and am referring to this link for the installation :https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-repo-excerpt/5.6/en/linux-installation-yum-repo.html I finished the first two steps and when I try doing Step 3, I get the following error:

```
Loaded plugins: refresh-packagekit, rhnplugin, security
This system is receiving updates from RHN Classic or RHN Satellite.
Setting up Install Process
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package mysql-community-server.x86_64 0:5.7.10-2.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: mysql-community-common(x86-64) = 5.7.10-2.el6 for package: mysql-community-server-5.7.10-2.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: mysql-community-client(x86-64) = 5.7.10-2.el6 for package: mysql-community-server-5.7.10-2.el6.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package mysql-community-client.x86_64 0:5.7.10-2.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: mysql-community-libs(x86-64) = 5.7.10-2.el6 for package: mysql-community-client-5.7.10-2.el6.x86_64
---> Package mysql-community-common.x86_64 0:5.7.10-2.el6 will be installed
--> Running transaction check
---> Package mysql-community-libs.x86_64 0:5.7.10-2.el6 will be obsoleting
---> Package mysql-libs.x86_64 0:5.5.47-1.el6.remi will be obsoleted
--> Processing Dependency: libmysqlclient.so.18()(64bit) for package: php-mysql-5.4.45-3.el6.remi.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libmysqlclient.so.18(libmysqlclient_16)(64bit) for package: php-mysql-5.4.45-3.el6.remi.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libmysqlclient.so.18(libmysqlclient_18)(64bit) for package: php-mysql-5.4.45-3.el6.remi.x86_64
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: php-mysql-5.4.45-3.el6.remi.x86_64 (@remi)
           Requires: libmysqlclient.so.18()(64bit)
           Removing: mysql-libs-5.5.47-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (@remi)
               libmysqlclient.so.18()(64bit)
           Obsoleted By: mysql-community-libs-5.7.10-2.el6.x86_64 (mysql57-community)
               Not found
Error: Package: php-mysql-5.4.45-3.el6.remi.x86_64 (@remi)
           Requires: libmysqlclient.so.18(libmysqlclient_18)(64bit)
           Removing: mysql-libs-5.5.47-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (@remi)
               libmysqlclient.so.18(libmysqlclient_18)(64bit)
           Obsoleted By: mysql-community-libs-5.7.10-2.el6.x86_64 (mysql57-community)
               Not found
Error: Package: php-mysql-5.4.45-3.el6.remi.x86_64 (@remi)
           Requires: libmysqlclient.so.18(libmysqlclient_16)(64bit)
           Removing: mysql-libs-5.5.47-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (@remi)
               libmysqlclient.so.18(libmysqlclient_16)(64bit)
           Obsoleted By: mysql-community-libs-5.7.10-2.el6.x86_64 (mysql57-community)
               Not foundenter code here
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

Answer (score 1):

I will recommend to move from **php-mysql** to **php-mysqlnd** (which provides the same set of extensions: mysql, mysqli and pdo_mysql), and thus, get rid of dependency on libmysqlclient:

```
# yum shell --enablerepo=remi
> remove php-mysql
> install php-mysqlnd
> run
```

Notice: PHP 5.4 is now EOL, I also recommend to upgrade to 5.5 or 5.6. And 5.4 is also the last version to provides php-mysql, newer RPM versions only have php-mysqlnd.

Comment: Got this error:   > install php-mysqlnd
                          Setting up Install Process
                          No package php-mysqlnd available.

Comment: You have php-mysql-5.4.45-3.el6.remi.x86_64, from "remi" repository which is not enabled by default , so you need to add --enablerepo=remi to  yum command

Comment: Could you please type the entire command plesae!

Comment: Full command is in the above answer

Answer (score 0):

try installing mysql from epel repository.
http://www.tecmint.com/how-to-enable-epel-repository-for-rhel-centos-6-5/
after that follow installing LAMP.

Comment: rpm -ivh epel-release-7-5.noarch.rpm
error: epel-release-7-5.noarch.rpm: headerRead failed: hdr blob(3484): BAD, read returned 2696
error: epel-release-7-5.noarch.rpm cannot be installed

Answer (score 0):

Already mysql installed in your box. So remove all the old mysql from your box.
& then do your installation process.

Run below command to check for already installed package.
rpm -qa | grep 'mysql'

Remove all the mysql package get from above command.
before start installing new package.
run "yum clean all"

Then check your linux version & architecture, proceed with your installation as per link. ( https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-repo-excerpt/5.6/en/linux-installation-yum-repo.html )